# I am not getting the value from sql data using request.QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am creating a simple page using asp.net webform & C# along with SQL. Please take a look at the code which will be easier to understand

```
 public string settype;
         int qid;

settype = System.Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["settype"]);
qid = System.Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["qid"]);
```

There is a table with settype and qid, with above code I get the settype value but I cannot get the value for qid. it stays null. Am I missing something?

and datatype for qid in sql is  numeric(18,0)

Answer (score 1):

For Receiving the value(18,0) from Query String....you have to set data type as double..

```
Double qid;
qid = Convert.ToDouble(Request.QueryString["qid"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Before fetching the QueryString value we have to check the null condition it is best practices. Below the code 
decimal qid=0.0M;
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["qid"]))
          qid= Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["qid"])
```